# Inserting array into MySQL - nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql

I've been working on a project that involves web scraping. I've successfully scraped a web page and inserted values into an array. After loop console.log of array looks like: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]. But when I insert an array into MySQL table, it pushes all data of array in ONE row. If I place query loop inside of a loop where I scrape single data, then the table is populated:
id_1 1
id_2 1,2
id_3 1,2,3
id_4 1,2,3,4

Where I expect it to be:
id_1 1,
id_2 2,
id_3 3 and so on.

[Picture of a loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upSWV.png)

[Error because it's trying to push the entire array in first id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xsoqv.png)

Comment: If you want to insert value in multiple rows, you might need to prepare your query accordingly, it should be a value not an array. Currently, it's trying to add the array in price column.

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari I've tried with scraped data (tried without pushing it into an array) but the same thing happens. Is any method that could help me?

Comment: `INSERT INTO tbl_name (price) VALUES(12),(23),(12);`

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari what does (12),(23),(12) represents? And also is the query loop in the right place?

Comment: Yes, something like this: `prices = [12, 40, 50];
let query = "INSERT INTO price (price) VALUES";
prices.forEach(price => query += `(${price}), `)`

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari could i reach you at twitter? Let me know if u opens ur dm's